# Finding C-convex holes in a planar point set

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, computational-geometry

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find convex holes in a given point set.
The problem is

> Given $n$ points in the Euclidan plane, and a constant $c$, determine how many empty convex polygons $P_1, \dots, P_k$ there are, such that for each $i = 1,\dots,k$; $P_i$ has exactly $c$ vertices from the given point set.

Although there are some papers that considers finding possibly non convex holes [[1]](http://www.eurocg2019.uu.nl/papers/22.pdf) [[2]](https://cg.cs.uni-bonn.de/aigaion2root/attachments/bendels-2006-detecting.pdf) [[3]](https://ed.iitm.ac.in/~raman/agcl/islandDetectSMI17_R2.pdf), and some others that show existence of such holes [[4]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772112001599) [[5]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925772118300865), I could not find a paper that describes an algorithm to find them.

Obviously, a naive algorithm that runs in $\mathcal{O}(n^c)$ comes to mind, where each $c$-subset is traversed. However, I would like to know whether there exists a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: What's an empty polygon?  Also, the problem statement does not depend on $c$, so something seems missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Counting Convex Polygons in Planar Point Sets" ([link](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rote/Papers/pdf/Counting+convex+polygons+in+planar+point+sets.pdf)) Mitchell et al. show an algorithm which can do this in time $O(cn^3)$.

Note however that if you need to report those polygons then you can't do better than $O(n^c)$ as there might be $\Omega(n^c)$ such polygons to begin with (consider for example $n$ points in convex position).